# VS2012 project x86 target not running on 32 bit Windows XP

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, build, x86

I wrote a WPF application using VS2012 on windows 8 computer (x86) and I want it to run on Windows XP x86. When I try to run the program I get error "... is not a valid windows 32 application." I've tried change Platform target to x86 and Any CPU,But have the same error. How can I fix it?

Comment: what is the target framework in your project and is it available on your XP machine?

Comment: The target framework is .NET Framework 4.0.3, it's available on XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you target .NET 4.0 (not 4.5). Also make sure both [.NET 4.0 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=17718) and [Reliability Update 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600217) have been installed on your XP machine (it must be an XP SP3 machine).

Comment: The target is .NET 4.0, and Reliability Update 2 has been installed. But it won't work.

Comment: That's odd. Generate a new .NET Console app with VS2012 Wizard, set the target as .NET 4.0/x86, compile and run it under your XP. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

For C/C++ projects you need to:

- Go to project *Properties* -> *Configuration Properties* -> *General*
- Change the *Platform Toolset* to **Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp)**

You'll need at least VS2012 SP1 installed for that option to be available.
Applications may need *msvcrt110.dll*.

For more details see:
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/linking-applications-using-visual-studio-2012-to-run-on-windows-xp